# How to create Access (view page) role in yii?

Tags: roles, access-rules, getstate

How to create access role in yii and where in yii application part ?

I want to create access role in yii application but I have a problem and don't know about where to assign role in yii like I have three department role:

1.admin -: admin have a all access role in our application

2.staff -: staff same of page and access role like to edit or update

3.user -: user have a all access page only viewing in our application

These type of role can set in controller but I can justify where to write all access in yii and how to set access role ,

I try this type code in controller and here I have role in session I
cheeked by using this:

**admin but this con't access these type page  and show error message (anotharization action )**

```
 echo Yii::app()->user->getState('roles'); 
    public function accessRules()
   {
      return array(  
           array('allow', //allow admin user to perform 'index'&'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
                'roles'=>array('admin'),
                ),
      );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii implements a hierarchical RBAC scheme via its CWebApplication ->authManager application component,
Take a look at this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/)

Comment: I have studied this but exactly I am not getting how to code this?